Run only tagged scenarios from console by maven
I would like to have the ability to run scenarios and control which ones I want to execute.
I found that there is an option (https://qaautomation.expert/2023/03/29/run-cucumber7-with-junit5-tests-from-maven-command-line/) to do this with the same technology stack I am using. Interestingly, it doesn't work exactly as presented in the article –
when I try to limit it to a specific tag, nothing happens.
When i call:
mvn clean test

The runner detects all tests, but when I try to narrow it down to a specific tag, nothing is executed. Has anyone else encountered this problem?
For example:
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@ValidData"

and there is my feature file
Feature: Some crazy feature

  @ValidData
  Scenario: Test
    Given Prepare for testing
    And Testing
    And After test

  @InvalidData
  Scenario: Another test
    Given Prepare for testing
    And Login
    And After test

RunCucumberTest
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty,io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm")
public class RunCucumberTests
{

}

And the output:
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running RunCucumberTests
[WARNING] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 0.083 s - in RunCucumberTests
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[WARNING] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.788 s

Should i do some changes with maven-surifer-plugin?

Did you read https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#tags?

If you need a working project, have a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/tree/main
